# Maven clean install only works with sudo on a certain project

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to build my project but when I do `mvn clean install` I get `package javax.xml.ws does not exist`. In the same project if I do `sudo mvn clean install` I get no errors and my project run smoothly!

I have installed the following maven version

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.9.1, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
```

I have both java 8 and java 11 installed but currently I use java 8

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~18.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

Maven is installed under user repo so why does it need `sudo`?
It's the only project that something like that occurs as I have been using `mvn clean install` in other projects without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your maven is using Java version: "11.0.9.1" although you have openjdk version "1.8.0_275". From Java 9 it has deprecated six modules that contain Java EE APIs and they are going to be removed in future releases. Now your maven is compiling using Java 11, which does not have these packages.
Since you have Java 8 Installed you can configure maven to use Java 8.

Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to your JDK 8 installation and then try "mvn --version". If environment variable is properly set you should see java version changed to java 8.